# Lightning Component Account CountryCode StateCode dependent picklist not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

```
    <aura:attribute name="dealerAccount" type="Account"    default="{'sobjectType':'Account'}"/>

    <force:inputField  value="{!v.dealerAccount.ShippingCountryCode}"/>
    <force:inputField  value="{!v.dealerAccount.ShippingStateCode}"/>
```

But the problem is on selection of country state is not changing.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you are getting those rendered as "read-only" too. If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:inputField/documentation), dependent picklists are **not** supported with `force:inputField`

> Dependent picklists and rich text fields are **not** supported. State and country fields in addresses display as read-only fields

To be able to utilize dependent picklists, use [lightning:inputField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputField/documentation) instead.

Comment: <lightning:inputField fieldName="ShippingCountryCode" /> --- Field not visible
<lightning:inputField fieldName="ShippingStateCode" /> --- Field not visible

<lightning:inputField fieldName="ShippingCountry" /> --- Field visible as text not picklist
<lightning:inputField fieldName="ShippingState" /> --- Field visible as text not picklist

Comment: @PrasantaKumarPardhi You need to open that as another question. With what you had asked in this question first has been answered. If you implement anything other than that and does not work, that classifies as a new question.